# SQL Server Delete/Insert based on textbox can't work. - VS 2010

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

My VS 2010 program has a Datagridview which loads data from a SQL Server database and now I'm adding several textboxes to add new rows & update existing rows.

Here is the sub for the button:

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.IO


Public Class macmaster

'variables to be used'  
Dim myCmd As SqlCommand         'create SQL command'
Dim myReader As SqlDataReader   'pull data'
Dim dt As New DataTable         'store data'
Dim intResult As MsgBoxResult
Dim strSQL As String

 Private Sub MacSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MacSave.Click

    Dim myConn = New SqlConnection("server=server;database=SQL;uid=pro;pwd=abcd") 'form connection'

    Try 'alert user if any fields not filled in'

        If Me.MacNm.Text.Trim = "" Then

            '**this portion of code not relevant**'

        Else 'proceed next step if all fields ok.'

            intResult = MsgBox("Are you sure to Add/Update?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel)
            If intResult = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then

                'call connection (myConn)'
                myConn.Open()

                myCmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [SQL].[dbo].[Mac] WHERE Machine='" & MacNm.Text & "'"

                myCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [SQL].[dbo].[Mac](Machine, PIC, Die) VALUES('" & MacNm.Text & "','" & MacPIC.Text & "','" & MacDie.Text & "')"

                MsgBox("Record Added!")

                myConn.Close()

            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "btnAdd_Click Exception")
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

During testing, I tried out the button out. The code runs all the way till I received the message box saying record is added.

But checking the SQL Server database, I see the data didn't even change. None of the 2 part SQL query triggered. I even tested out both queries on SQL Server as well. Works fine. Is it how I refer to  the textbox that have problems?

Comment: myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();... you are missing this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing ExecuteNonQuery().

```
myCmd = New SqlCommand()

myCmd.Connection= myConn

mnyCmd.CommandType= CommandType.Text

Dim commands As String
commands= "DELETE FROM [SQL].[dbo].[Mac] WHERE Machine='" & MacNm.Text & "';"&"INSERT INTO [SQL].[dbo].[Mac](Machine, PIC, Die) VALUES('" & MacNm.Text & "','" & MacPIC.Text & "','" & MacDie.Text & "')"

myCmd.CommandText = commands

myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

MsgBox("Record Added!")
```

Comment: Tried it. After I confirm to add entry and the next action is the delete SQL query, the next line jumps into exception, giving me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Comment: @hjh93 After which line are you getting this error?

Comment: after it passes `myCmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [SQL].[dbo].[Mac] WHERE Machine='" & MacNm.Text & "'"`

Comment: That doesn't address the issue that only the `INSERT` will be performed.

Comment: btw the `insert` query also goes to exception as well, if I comment out my `delete` query.

Comment: @hjh93 I just realised you dont even have a SqlCommand instance in your code. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I actually have that. Its outside the sub on Public Class. I'll amend the code to include it.

Comment: @hjh93 You only have its declaration in your code. But you have not created its instance anywhere in your code using New operator. Thats why it is throwing- Object reference error. Check my latest answer.

Comment: Ok.Trying your new code but this portion seems to be having problems.      
on the 2 rows after `myCmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text`

Comment: `String` is class type and can't be used as expression and `commands` not declared

Comment: @hjh93 Solved it. Check again

Answer (score 1):

You are going about this in completely the wrong way. What you should be doing is:

1. Use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` by calling `Fill`.
2. Bind the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource`.
3. Bind the `BindingSource` to your `DataGridView` as well as your `TextBoxes`.
4. Add and delete rows through the `BindingSource` and edit rows directly.
5. Save all the changes back to the database in one go by calling `Update` on the data adapter and passing the `DataTable`.

You would add the `BindingSource` to the form in the designer. The data-binding would then look something like this:

```vb
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "Column1")
```

Selecting a row in the grid will then populate the `Textboxes` with the field values for that row. You can then edit in the individual controls and commit the change implicitly by navigating to another row or explicitly by calling `EndEdit` on the `BindingSource`. To delete the selected row, call `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource`. To add a new row, call `AddNew` on the `BindingSource`. I haven't tested but I believe that that new row is immediately accessible via the `TextBoxes`. Again, commit the change implicitly or explicitly. In case it's not obvious, the `BindingSource` is there to work with bound data.

If it's not already clear, all those changes are made locally, only to the `DataTable`. The database is updated when you call `Update` on the data adapter. You will need to either use a command builder or else create the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` yourself.

Comment: This is a good pattern. Very solid. A minor suggestion: you might consider using `NameOf(MyTextBox.Text)` and `Column1.Name` to avoid the Magic String problem.